# Selenium ChromeDriver в консольном приложении забирает управление

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, selenium, chromedriver

Второй раз натыкаюсь на следующую проблему: есть телеграм бот в консольньном приложении, который использует определенный метод для получения обновлений с сервера, как и другие боты, которые мне доводилось видеть. Но т.к. в некоторых моментах используется хром драйвер (который нативно использует вывод в ту же консоль), основной цикл бота нарушается и программа быстро приходит к завершению. собственно, можно ли запретить боту использовать мое консольное окно, или же это делается иначе? Гуглил, ничего подобного не нашел.

Comment: Какой смысл боту, консольному, ставить селениум? Не лучше отловить нужные запросы и послать их напрямую, простым C# кодом?

Comment: Много манипуляций с кликами и прочим + обход блокировок, на которые натыкается request. Да и пусть даже мой подход странный, не спорю, но проблему это не отменяет. Неужели нельзя сделать AllocConsole или что-то вроде этого?